# Best practices for Docker compose testing?

Tags: docker, testing, docker-compose

In [complex orchestrations of docker-compose.yaml stacks](https://github.com/unee-t/bugzilla-customisation/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), I'm keen to do a simple integration test that shows the system works. I'm not entirely sure though this might be called an "end to end" test.

I've seen https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core used in helm charts, though not so much in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/search?q=bats+filename%3Adocker-compose.yml).

Is there some other testing method that I am missing? Or is using bats in a docker-compose context, a reasonable approach? My end goal is that the application can be testing in some CI service like TravisCI/CircleCI using a simple `docker-compose.yml` & a command not too dissimilar to `docker-compose up`